# PHPExcel not only crashing Apache, but also deleting httpd.exe

Tags: php, apache, xampp, phpexcel

I've downloaded the 1.8 version of PHPExcel and sometimes, when I'm testing the "01simple.php"  sample (native), Apache crashes and also removes the httpd.exe file. This happens only when saving the file, doesn't happens when you're downloading.

I had to create a backup of httpd.exe and put into "apache\bin" every time it crashes.

Have no idea why this is happening. Anyone?

Using Xampp 1.8.3, Apache 2.4.9, Windows 7 x64, phpexcel 1.8.

Comment: Phew, never heard of that before. I'm surprised the web server even has the necessary permissions to remove itself. Would you edit into the question what version of Windows you are on, and which minor version of Apache? (Btw, mostly there is no need to add 'Edit' markers into questions, since they are written for posterity).

Comment: Yes, it was the first time that something like this happens to me. And tooks me a while to figure that it was removing the httpd file.. Btw, i've added more information about the versions.

Comment: Great. Don't forget to add your Apache **minor** version e.g. 2.4.6, as it might be relevant.

Comment: I'm not going to spend the rest of my life searching for something in PHPExcel that could crash apache and delete httpd.exe; but I can assure you that there's no rogue code anywhere in the official distribution that would do that

Comment: I've explained the scenario that crashes for me. It's a really easy scenario. If you run the very same file that i told in the first post 3 times, it will crash. I don't know either about httpd being removed, but something is causing it. And "coincidentally" it happened 10 times when i was doing my tests running the sample files of php excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible that PhpExcel could do such thing.

First you should make sure you downloaded PhpExcel from [official site](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

If problem still occurs, you should scan your computer and make sure if the problem is caused by PhpExcel. You wrote "sometimes" - and it could be just coincidence - maybe something else is removing your httpd.exe and you simply see it because you are now testing PhpExcel library.

Comment: Indeed. Is it possible that your anti-virus software is seeing httpd as a threat when running this particular test and thus quarantining httpd? I'd think that an anti-virus could get a bit trigger-happy seeing a local process downloading files... Check your anti-virus logs, or, if you can do it safely, disable the antivirus temporarily and see if the problem still happens.

Comment: Possible... possible.. i'll check it out, Matt. Thanks!

Comment: BINGO! Kaspersky was doing it! Thanks for the help, all!

Comment: My powers of remote diagnosis are clearly getting better :) Glad you got it sorted.